# Retrieving Twitter data from url in database

Tags: php, database, twitter, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to retrieve data from twitter api with twitter api exchange. I have a database on phpmyadmin with a lot of twitter links and I need to get the `followers_count` for each account. The code seems to run, but it is really slow and works one time out of ten. Here is my code :

```
<?php 


require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php'); 


$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "aaaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbbb",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' =>"cccccccccc",
    'consumer_key' => "dddddddddddd",
    'consumer_secret' => "eeeeeeeeee"
);


$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=rise', 'root', 'mali');
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM usa WHERE administrative_area_level_1 = "NY"');

while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())

{
    $id_twitter = str_replace('https://twitter.com/', '',$donnees['twitter']);
    $ta_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'; 
    $getfield = '?screen_name=' . $id_twitter;

    $requestMethod = 'GET';
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $follow_count=$twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
        ->buildOauth($ta_url, $requestMethod)
        ->performRequest();
    $data = json_decode($follow_count, true);

    $followers_count=$data[0]['user']['followers_count'];
    $screen_name = $data[0]['user']['screen_name'];

    echo $screen_name  . " : " . $followers_count . '<br>' ; 
}
?>
```

I'd rather be clear, i'm a total newbie at coding, please don't go too technical.
thank you for your help :)

Comment: I've removed your OAuth keys. Please revoke them on the Twitter website.

Comment: @TerenceEden Thank you, I changed some of the letters anyway before ^^. But you're right  I'll do it to be sure  thank you.